# Postgres service account on Windows best practice

Tags: postgresql

On Windows, by default PostgreSQL installation starts the service as Network Service and on Postgres data folder Network Service has permission. I landed in the situation wherein the installation folder was not having permission for Network Service and that made my application down. On manually starting service it says "Access denied". I found a way if I start the service using SYSTEM account it works fine.

But is this best way(simple & secure), I am just concerned if that is going to degrade the security of Postgres. Let me know.

Comment: Postgres will drop all elevated privileges on Windows when it starts, so there is no real problem using a "local system" account for the service